# Rendering a partial in rails. Specifying the partial for a resource gives an error, but not specifying a partial works fine. What gives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial, partials

I've got this working now quite accidentally, but I don't understand what causes it to break when I explicitly specify what partials are to be used for rendering the resource/s. Can anyone explain it?

The index template for my Posts controller contained the following line, which was giving me an error:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts', collection: @posts %>
```

The error (in my browser) said:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index

Showing /Users/applebum/Sites/rails_projects/eventful2/app/views/posts/_posts.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `any?' for #<Post:0x000001064b21f0>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% if posts.any? %>
2:  <div id="posts">
3:      <% posts.each do |post| %>
4:          <%= render partial: "posts/post", locals: { post: post } %>
```

Changing the problem line to

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

made the error disappear and the posts appear (displayed nicely in markup from the appropriate partials) as I had wanted and expected them to.

Here's my _posts.html.erb partial:

```
<% if posts.any? %>
    <div id="posts">
        <% posts.each do |post| %>
            <%= render partial: "posts/post", locals: { post: post } %>
            <% # render :partial => "comments/comments", :collection => post.comments %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And the _post.html.erb partial it's referring to, if that matters:

```
<div class="post" id="post_<%= "#{post.id}" %>">

    <div class="post_inner">
        <%= link_to avatar_for(post.user, size: "small"), post.user.profile %>

        <div class="post_body">

            <div class="user-tools">
                <% if can? :destroy, post %>
                    <%= link_to '<i class="fi-x"></i>'.html_safe, post, :method => :delete, remote: true, :class => "delete", :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", :title => post.content %>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <h5 class="username">
                <%= link_to post.user.name, post.user.profile %> 
                <span class="timestamp">&bull; <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</span>
            </h5>

            <div class="content">
                <%= post.content %>
            </div>

            <ul class="foot">       
                <li>Like<li>
                <li>Share</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the relevant bits from the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :html, :js # Allow for AJAX requests as well as HTML ones.

    before_filter :load_postable

    load_and_authorize_resource

    def index
        @post = Post.new
        @posts = @postable.posts
    end

    private #################

    def load_postable
        klass = [User, Event].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] } # Look for which one of these there's a ***_id parameter name for
        @postable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"]) # Call find on that, passing in that parameter. eg Event.find(1)
    end
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? I couldn't find anything in the Layouts and Rendering guide at rubyonrails.org.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from assuming `:collection` and `@posts` mean the same thing when rendering. From [Rails Docs (point 3.4.5)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

> Partials are very useful in rendering collections. When you pass a collection to a partial via the :collection option, the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection

So, if you use that, for each post, you will be doing `post.any?` which fails as `any?` isn't defined for a single post.

From the same docs, you should check if render returns Nil to see if the collection is empty:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<%= render(@posts) || "There are no posts." %>
```

PD: Use the partial to render only one post, not all of them.

GL & HF.

Comment: Ohhh now I get it. Your PD did it. :D Thanks!